# pdf for the sum of squared iid normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to find the distribution/pdf for the sum of squared $X_i$ iid observations from the normal distribution $X_1 ,..., X_n$ ~ $N(\alpha , \alpha)$, i.e. $X_1 ^2 + X_2 ^2 +...+ X_n ^2$.

I was able to find [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89779/sum-of-squares-of-normal-distributions) on Overflow, but I would really appreciate some clarification.

Comment: This might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution

Comment: @David thanks for this, but I am not quite getting the connection. I was hoping that someone would be able to explain more fully.